# Pass table info to php and the upload it to the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Hey I have this table inside a form

```
<form  method="post">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="factura">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Descripción</th>
                  <th class="text-center" style="width: 100px;">Cantidad</th>
                  <th class="text-right" style="width: 120px;">Precio Unitario</th>
                  <th class="text-right" style="width: 120px;">Total</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>


              </tbody>
            </table>
              <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" id="save" name="saveInvoice" disabled="true" value="Guardar">
            </form>
```

I'm adding items to this table via Javascript this way.

```
  var titulo = document.getElementById("newItemTitle").value;
  var descripcion = document.getElementById("newItemDescription").value;
  var cantidad = document.getElementById("newItemQuantity").value;
  var precio = document.getElementById("newItemPrice").value;

  var totalItem = precio * cantidad;

  valorTotal += totalItem;

  var precioFix = precio * 1;


  var table = document.getElementById("factura");
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell2.innerHTML = '<p class="font-w600 push-10">' + titulo +'</p><div class="text-muted" >' + descripcion + '</div>';
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell3.className = "text-center";
  cell3.innerHTML = '<span class="badge badge-primary">'+ cantidad +'</span>';
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell4.className = "text-right";

  cell4.innerHTML = '$' + formatMoney(precioFix, '') + '';
  var cell5 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell5.className = "text-right";
  cell5.innerHTML = '$' + formatMoney(totalItem, '') + '';
```

Now I want to upload all this info in the database, I'm trying doing something like this where I pass the table info to a post and the I use javascript to loop into every row and adds it to the database. But it's not working. Can someone help me please?

```
<?php
if($_POST['saveInvoice']) {

  $table = $_POST['factura'];

  ?>
  <script>
  var table = <?php echo($table) ?>
  var rowLength = table.rows.length;

  for(var i=0; i<rowLength; i+=1){
  var row = table.rows[i];

  //your code goes here, looping over every row.
  //cells are accessed as easy

  console.log(row);

  }
  </script>
  <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: you are mixing serverside with client side.. maybe learn some ajax?

Comment: The php code is executed on the server side... your javascript is on the client side so it will run once the page as loaded (sorta, not going in details)

Comment: Mmm ok, soo what exactly should I do so i can upload this info in a easy way to my db?

Comment: you can use `jquery ajax` and send `$('form').html()` to `data` option to your server file, so that you have `table` html

Comment: Thanks @MaheshSinghChouhan I'll try doing that!

Comment: @Gonzalo4488 wait i am posting answer with some ajax code example as per your requirement so that it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jquery ajax`

Update your html code like this and add `jquery ajax` function as below:

**Html Code:**

```
<form  method="post" onsubmit="return sendTable()" id="tableForm">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="factura">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Descripción</th>
          <th class="text-center" style="width: 100px;">Cantidad</th>
          <th class="text-right" style="width: 120px;">Precio Unitario</th>
          <th class="text-right" style="width: 120px;">Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" id="save" name="saveInvoice" disabled="true" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
var sendTable = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "SERVER_FILE_PATH.php",
        data : {table: $('#tableForm').html()},
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(){

        }
    })
    return false;
}
```

Add your server file path for `url` in ajax function and echo `$_POST['table']` on your server to get the html, Also make sure to add `jquery` library on your page if you have not loaded yet.

Comment: Welcome, you can mark this answer as helpful, so that it helps others!